# Splash screen showing more than once

Tags: android, splash-screen

A splash screen is supposed to only appear once when the app is installed.

AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name=".Splash"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Splash.java

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

private static boolean splashLoaded = false;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!splashLoaded) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        int secondsDelayed = 5;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, secondsDelayed * 500);

        splashLoaded = true;
    }
    else {
        Intent goToMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
        goToMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(goToMainActivity);
        finish();
    }
}
}
```

But mine doesn't work even after I put `android:noHistory="true"`
Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: when you can run your app then every time your splashLoaded variable is initialized that's why every time your splash screen is display. Use share Preference to store data globally

Comment: What exactly you want to do, are you calling the splash class again from different class ??

Comment: See my answer below for using shared preferences to persist the state of the splashLoaded variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static boolean splashLoaded = false;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        splashLoaded = prefs.getBoolean("Splash_Loaded", false);

        if (!splashLoaded) {
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            int secondsDelayed = 5;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, secondsDelayed * 500);

            splashLoaded = true;
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Splash_Loaded", true);
            editor.apply();
        } else {
            Intent goToMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                goToMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(goToMainActivity);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the Application-class to store the variable beyond different activities. Application is only launched when the application starts, the activity is launched every time you open the specific window. See this link for more information on extending the Application class: https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/&ved=0ahUKEwi3qIaD-KzOAhVCWxoKHURMDgcQFggdMAE&usg=AFQjCNF0ZhP1KDNAUnJNY0YyvZvrm_Vn8g

Answer (score 0):

Use this code -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("AnyName",MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean loaded = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("loaded",false);

    if (!loaded) {
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor2.putBoolean("loaded", true);
        editor2.commit();
        int secondsDelayed = 5;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, secondsDelayed * 500);

        }
    else {
        Intent goToMainActivity = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
        goToMainActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(goToMainActivity);
        finish();
    }
}
```